# Return a value from python script to the a makefile variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, makefile

I have a requirement where I have to run a python script through a makefile. Python script performs some calculations and return a value. I want to get that value in that makefile variable. How I can do that?

I want something like this:

**mymakefile.mke**

```
$output = python process.py
```

**process.py**

```
import os

def main():
    value = "01.00.00"
    return value
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: use `print()` instead of `return`

Answer (score 3):

If you want the value in a *Make* variable, you can do this:

```
output := $(shell python process.py)
```

(Note the use of `:=` rather than `=`, because if you use `=`, Make will run the script every time it evaluates the variable.)

If you want the value in a *shell* variable within a recipe, look at the syntax you would use on the command line in your shell, which is probably something like:

```
output=$(python process.py); echo $output
```

but in a makefile rule you must escape the dollar signs with more dollar signs:

```
some_target:
    output=$$(python process.py); echo $$output
```

Note that since each line of a recipe executes in its own sub-shell, the assignment and use of the variable must be on the same line; it won't survive to the next line.

Comment: When I run 'output := $(shell python process.py)' it gives me following error:  'output' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Comment: @NaveedAhmad: Because you introduced spaces. Instead of seeing the statement as an *assignment* (with the assignment operator in the middle), the shell sees what looks like the command `output` with some arguments to the right, and it complains that it doesn't know how to "output".